# How to ignore Python class attributes?

Tags: python, python-2.7

If we have a class with a few default arguments set to None, how do we ignore them if they are None, and use them if they are not (or at least one of them is not None)?

```
class Foo:
def __init__(self, first=1, second=2, third=3, fourth=None, fifth=None):
    self.first = first
    self.second = second
    self.third = third
    self.fourth = fourth
    self.fifth = fifth
    self.sum = self.first + self.second + self.third + self.fourth + self.fifth
    return self.sum

>>> c = Foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#120>", line 1, in <module>
c = Foo()
File "<pyshell#119>", line 8, in __init__
self.sum = self.first + self.second + self.third + self.fourth + self.fifth
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Comment: Why not just set the default to `0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def __init__(self, first=1, second=2, third=3, fourth=None, fifth=None):
    if first is None:
        first = 0
    else:
        self.first = first
```

Then it will add zero with no side effects instead of `None`

You could also change the part where you add them up and test for `None` first but this is probably less typing.

Answer (score 0):

```
  class test(object):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key in ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth']:
            self.__dict__[key]=value
        else:
            pass #or alternatively "raise KeyError" or your custom msg


    def get_sum(self):
        sum=0
        for x in self.__dict__:
            sum+=self.__dict__[x]
        return sum

nk=test()
nk['first']=3
nk['fifth']=5
nk['tenth']=10
print nk.get_sum()
```

output:

```
>>> 8
```